# Incoming calls from Client - same or different thread?

Tags: c#, wcf, server

I have a "server" program that receives calls from "client" that ask to do stuff. I wonder how these calls are actually done - is a new thread being created?

I'm asking because these calls need to wait until certain conditions are met in the server, and if I do `while(conditionIsNotMet) Thread.sleep(x);` - I'm noticing some problems in the execution of my main thread. The problem is that while it does indeed wait, the main execution thread seems to be much slower, and also, to be interrupted in some way that it creates bad results.

This is the architecture:

[image]

My question is, does the call (purple arrow) interrupts the main thread (that created the service), the main thread (that is executing most of the work), or does it create a new thread?

Also, any idea why the `while(conditionIsNotMet) Thread.sleep(x);` could cause problems?

Is there a better way to do it in order to achieve the same result?

More code:

```
public class MyServerCommands : MyInterface
{
    public void SomeFunction(some parameters)
    {
        while (conditionIsNotMet)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(SomeTime);
        }
      // some more code - mainly, update a google spreadsheet
    }
}

public partial class ProgramA : Form
{
     // code for starting WCF server, creating background workers, and firing them

     private void BkwMain_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
     {
         if (conditionIsNotMet)
         {
              // do work, mainly update google sheet
         }
         conditionIsNotMet = false;
     }
}
```

**UPDATE**: So after playing around a bit, I think I can conclude that the thread  that creates the server is the one that will have to share it's commands. Since in my app (Program A) it was the main thread, also responsible for UI, this caused the UI to lag until the while loop ended. 
My solution for it, for now, is to create the server in another thread, or a (parent) form and try to hide it (as it will lag also). 
If there are better solutions, please let me know.

**UPDATE/CLARIFICATION**: what I mean by "creating the server" is the following command: `Host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyServerCommands), baseAddress);`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your service's [InstanceContextMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ConcurrencyMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.concurrencymode(v=vs.110).aspx) are.

I believe the `ConcurrencyMode` default is single threaded, so if you are running a single service instance (`InstanceContextMode.Single`) then yes, your main thread will be blocking further calls.

You need `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` if you want to be able to service calls on different threads, but obviously this opens up other threading concerns.

See [Sessions, Instancing, and Concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/sessions-instancing-and-concurrency) for more info.

As an aside, I wouldn't recommend `Thread.Sleep()` in a while loop for waiting. It would be better to wait on some kind of synchronization object such a `ManualResetEvent`.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at these links.